# how to add border to header and body of tabpanel xtype

Tags: css, extjs, sass

Creating an EXT js file:

Add border to header and body of `tabpanel`.

I have tried adding below stuff in .scss file, but did not work.

```
*.scss
.maintabpanel1 {

 .x-tab-bar-plain { border:1px solid red !important;

}

.x-tab-bar-top+.x-panel-body, .x-panel.x-tabpanel-child {

  border: 1px solid green !important;`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: .x-tab-bar-plain is missing a closing }

Comment: sorry i missed it, but even with the closing braces (}) the css does not take effect.                                                                                             
    .x-tab-bar-plain {
        border: 1px solid orangered !important;
        background: orangered !important;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide [`cls`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tab.Panel.html#cfg-cls) and [`bodyCls`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tab.Panel.html#cfg-bodyCls) to your [`tabpanel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tab.Panel.html).

- An **`cls`** optional extra CSS class that will be added to this component's Element. The value can be a string, a list of strings separated by spaces, or an array of strings. This can be useful for adding customized styles to the component or any of its children using standard CSS rules.
- A **`bodyCls`** class, space-delimited string of classes, or array of classes to be applied to the panel's body element.

In this **[gitlab-repo](https://gitlab.com/njdhv105/ExtJS-GeoLocation/tree/20180319/tab-panel-scss)**, I have created a demo using **ExtJS6.2**. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirements.

[screenshot from my local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua63T.jpg).

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.define('GeoLocation.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'app-main',
    cls: 'x-geo-tab',
    bodyCls: 'x-geo-tab-body',
    controller: 'main',
    titleRotation: 0,
    tabRotation: 0,
    activeTab: 0,
    items: [{
        title: 'Tab 1',
        html: 'it is tab 1'
    }, {
        title: 'Tab 2',
        html: 'it is tab 2'
    }, {
        title: 'Tab 3',
        html: 'it is tab 3'
    }]
});
```

> CSS part

```
.x-geo-tab {
    .x-tab-bar-default {
        background-color: #ece2e2;
        border: 2px solid red !important;
        padding: 5px;
        .x-tab-bar-strip-default {
            background-color: red;
            height: 2px !important;
        }
    }
    .x-geo-tab-body {
        border: 2px solid green !important;
        padding: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Narendra, But the above changes are not working when added in .scss file . But when i added style property as below it worked.

Comment: {
                        xtype: 'tabpanel',
                        style: { borderColor:'#dde3ee', borderStyle: 'solid' , borderWidth: '1px' },
                        region: 'center',
                        id:bid("mainTabPanel" + keyFieldValue),
                        renderTo: document.body,
                        activeTab: 0,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        deferredRender: false,
                        frame: false,
                         }, items: [{
                         title: 'General Info',
                         ,}] }

Comment: Can you provide your code library or repo? so I can be try to resolve  your issue.

Comment: xtype: 'tabpanel',
    style: { borderColor:'#dde3ee',borderStyle: 'solid' , borderWidth: '1px' },
    //cls: kve.WS_TAB_PNL_CLS,
    region: 'center',
    id:bid("mainTabPanel" + keyFieldValue),
    renderTo: document.body,
    activeTab: 0,
    autoScroll: true,
    deferredRender: false,
    frame: false,
    ...

Comment: Please provide your repo so I can try to solve @user3285402

Comment: Don't have repository. Below is .scss             .slpt-webserviceFieldEditor-tabPanel {
    border-color: $slpt-webservicefieldeditor-tab-panel-style-borderColor;
    border-style: $slpt-webservicefieldeditor-tab-panel-style-borderStyle;
    border-width: $slpt-webservicefieldeditor-tab-panel-style-borderWidth;
  }

Comment: Ok just go with download or clone my repo and check in your local what's different or may be something else you missed